# Regular Expression for specific number of special character

Tags: java, regex

I need only specific number of special characters in a password. I tried the following regex

```
(?=.*[$@!%*?&]{1})
```

It takes special character from that set but accepts even multiple special characters.

{1} means number of characters from the set I am allowing the string to validate.

For example,

`Alpha1?` should be true for the above regular expression

`@lpha1?` should not be validated by above regex because now it has 2 characters from that set.

Can someone please help?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the specific number that you need? What is your input?

Comment: What did you expect the regex to do? Actually, what is it you want *a* regex to do? I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve. Maybe if you explain better, and/or show examples, it would help. --- *Side note:* Why do you have two `$` in that character class? Why do you have `{1}`, since removing it means exactly the same thing?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149) --- Actually, I don't see *any* question is that Question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`^[^$@!%*?&\n]*[$@!%*?&][^$@!%*?&\n]*$`

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `[^$@!%*?&\n]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that does NOT fall in these set of characters: `$`, `@`, `!`, `%`, `?`, `&` or a newline character
- `[$@!%*?&]` - matches one occurrence of one of these characters: `$`, `@`, `!`, `%`, `?`, `&`
- `[^$@!%*?&\n]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that does NOT fall in these set of characters: `$`, `@`, `!`, `%`, `?`, `&` or a newline character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mmavnd/1)

**JAVA Code:([Generated here](https://regex101.com/r/Mmavnd/1/codegen?language=java))**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^[^$@!%*?&\\n]*[$@!%*?&][^$@!%*?&\\n]*$";
final String string = "abc12312\n"
     + "$123\n"
     + "$123?\n"
     + "Alpha1?\n"
     + "@lpha1?";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Update:

To get the strings with exactly 2 special characters, use this:

[`^(?:[^$@!%*?&\n]*[$@!%*?&]){2}[^$@!%*?&\n]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Mmavnd/2)

To get strings with exactly 5 spl. characters, replace {2} with {5}.

To get string with 2-5 special characters, use {2-5}

Comment: thanks for your answer. This works perfectly for allowing exactly 1 special character but how can I parameterize the number of special characters to be accepted from the user?

Comment: @Venky I have updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @Venky Please select it as the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: (^(?:[^$@!%*?&\n]*[$@!%*?&]){0-5}[^$@!%*?&\n]*$)   I tried to use the above regex, but getting this error:  PatternSyntaxException : unclosed counted closure, regex is enclosed inside bracket because I have other regex with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can use the method `replaceAll` to filter all characters up to your set of special characters. The method takes as argument a regular expression. The size of the result represents the count of special characters:

```
String password = "@foo!";

int size = password.replaceAll("[^$@$!%*?&]","").length();

System.out.println(size);
// will print 2
```